# Encoding Ruby - different behaviour on two machines

Tags: ruby, unicode, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a ruby script that uses inside a function that removes diacritics:

```
def remove_diacritics(text)
return text.tr!(
"ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåĀāĂăĄąÇçĆćĈĉĊċČčÐðĎďĐđÈÉÊËèéêëĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħÌÍÎÏìíîïĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłÑñŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøŌōŎŏŐőŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšſŢţŤťŦŧÙÚÛÜùúûüŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵÝýÿŶŷŸŹźŻżŽž",
"AAAAAAaaaaaaAaAaAaCcCcCcCcCcDdDdDdEEEEeeeeEeEeEeEeEeGgGgGgGgHhHhIIIIiiiiIiIiIiIiIiJjKkkLlLlLlLlLlNnNnNnNnnNnOOOOOOooooooOoOoOoRrRrRrSsSsSsSssTtTtTtUUUUuuuuUuUuUuUuUuUuWwYyyYyYZzZzZz")
end
```

I have the magic `# encoding: utf-8` at the beginning and I am getting some strange behaviour. It works on Mac but when I copy exactly the same file to Raspberry Pi, I am getting this error:

> remove_diacritics.rb:28:in `tr!': incompatible character encodings: US-ASCII and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

This seems to be a classic in help forums. The mesmerising thing is that it does work on one machine and doesn't on the other one, even though the versions of Ruby are exactly the same, ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you check the hash of the file to make sure it's exactly the same?  I know some file transfer programs try to make "helpful" changes when moving text files between machines (usually newline replacement) - seems unlikely here, but it _could_ be something like that...

Comment: Yes, the checksum is exactly the same...

Comment: If my memory is correct, unless you're explicitly setting the default internal encoding then it will be set for you based on the locale environment variables ( which in turn changes the encoding of strings read from files)

Comment: I thought that the `# encoding` comment changes the encoding. (Without the comment it does not work on Mac, so I assumed that it changes the encoding.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as Frederick points out. The `(en)coding:` comment determines the *source* encoding, but the error is caused by a mismatch with the *external* encoding. Your code produces CompatibilityError when run as

```
LANG=C ruby encoding.rb
```

but works with either of these

```
LANG=cs_CZ@UTF-8 ruby         encoding.rb
LANG=C           ruby -EUTF-8 encoding.rb
```

See [Ruby 1.9's Three Default Encodings](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings), a part of a great series explaining the Unicode situation in Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.

Comment: Aha, I didn't get Frederick's point, but now I see. Thanks for the clearance. The error was, indeed, caused by text being loaded as not utf-8, which is fixed by using `force_encoding('UTF-8')` with the input to the function above.